# Что возвращает функция?

Tags: c++, функции

int (*p[10]) ();   //Что возвращает функция ?

Comment: Любая функция из этого массива возвращает `int`

Comment: `p` — это массив из десяти элементов типа `T`, где `T` — это указатель на функцию, не имеющую параметров и возвращающую значение типа `int`.

Comment: Не надо сильно изменять вопросы. Вам ответили. Вы добавили фигурные скобки. Они вызывают конструктор по-умолчанию для десяти указателей.

Comment: Хм, вы отредактировали вопрос. Но мой предыдущий комментарий всё ещё верен. Только теперь к массиву `p` применяется [агрегатная инициализация](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Каждый элемент массива инициализируется нулевым указательным значением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы спрашиваете что возвращает функция, а показываете объявление массива указателей на функции.

Синтаксис типа указателей на функцию выглядит так :

```
тип_возвращяемый ( * ) ( список_типов_аргументов_функции ) ;
```

Объявление имени типа указателя на функцию :

```
typedef тип_возвращяемый ( * имя_типа_указателя_на_функцию ) 
  ( список_типов_аргументов_функции ) ;
```

Объявление переменной указателя на функцию :

```
тип_возвращяемый ( * имя_переменной_указателя_на_функцию ) 
  ( список_типов_аргументов_функции ) ;
```

Массив указателей на функции :

```
тип_возвращяемый ( * имя_массива_указателей_на_функции [ количество ] ) 
  ( список_типов_аргументов_функции ) ;
```

Пользоваться этим массивом просто, пробиваете указатель функции куда-нибудь в массив, и вызываете. Возвратится тип `int`.

```
int fun5 ( ) {
  return 5 ; }
...
int (*p[10]) ();
p [ 5 ] = & fun5 ;
int result = ( * p [ 5 ] ) ( ) ;
```

Вернётся число 5 .